# Does Spring has code quality tools?

Tags: java, xml, spring

XML files for Spring getting very big.
Does exist tool like PMD for java, that can check XML files and advice some about fixing?
Thanks.

Comment: Use annotations in spring if you don't like XML based approach.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever find a tool that will tell you "this XML document is too big"... Have you considered configuring spring to scan  you classpath for "all" *-context.xml files. Doing so will allow you to split up your XML configuration into separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... not specifically for xml, but java in general I'd suggest [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), and just came across [this](https://www.checkinginthecloud.com/saas/web/home/home;jsessionid=8AF19DADDE92FF858B285A12B88267E4) that's supposed to cover xml files as well.

And as it turns out, sonar does have an [xml plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin).

Comment: After 10 minutes using Sonar, I'm reasonably impressed with it.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: ... enjoy, it's a really great tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)

It has very nice integration and validation of spring context files.

Answer (score 0):

- *XML files for Spring getting very big*

Break it up in smaller component/layer files. XML is no different than any other configuration / codebase.

As far as helping you with Spring XML configuration *and* validating it, use IntelliJ with it's fantastic [Spring support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/spring_framework.html)

[image: IntelliJ Spring Support]